# Merge/synonymize [mailmerge] and [mail-merge]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, synonym-request

These two tags, [mailmerge](/questions/tagged/mailmerge) and [mail-merge](/questions/tagged/mail-merge), are the same thing, yet the tags link to two different sets of questions. Can these be merged and/or be given a synonym relationship?